# Can I aggregate a hierarchy of many-to-many relationships into a view?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm designing a relational database where users have certain access levels to its various parts. Lets call these parts `Company`, `Site`, and `Department`. A `Company` consists of one or more `Site`, and each `Site` consists of one or more `Department`. There is a many-to-many relationship between `User` and each of these entities, and each relation has an access level.

For example, `User1` may have an access level `3` to `CompanyA`, `User2` may have access level `2` to `CompanyA`'s `Site1`, and `User3` may have access level `1` to `Site1`'s `DepartmentX`. If a `User` has access to a certain entity, such as a company, they are assumed to have access to that entity's members as well.

I want to create a view that lists each `Department` and each `User`'s related access levels for that `Department`.

This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT
   Dept.Id AS 'DeptId', User.Id AS 'UserId',
   DeptAccess.RightsLevel AS 'DeptRightsLevel',
   SiteAccess.RightsLevel AS 'SiteRightsLevel'
FROM (Dept, User)
LEFT JOIN DeptAccess
   ON DeptAccess.DeptId=Dept.Id AND DeptAccess.UserId=User.Id
LEFT JOIN SiteAccess
   ON SiteAccess.SiteId=Dept.SiteId AND SiteAccess.UserId=User.Id
WHERE DeptAccess.RightsLevel IS NOT NULL OR SiteAccess.RightsLevel IS NOT NULL
```

This gives a table like the following (assume `DepartmentY` is also part of `Site1`):

```
DeptId | UserId | DeptRightsLevel | SiteRightsLevel
-------+--------+-----------------+------------------
X      | 2      | NULL            | 2
X      | 3      | 1               | NULL
Y      | 2      | NULL            | 2
```

How can I incorporate the `CompanyRightsLevel` into this table, so that a user with company-wide rights is shown in the table?

If my database setup is unclear please ask for clarification in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

After a short bit more of brainstorming I came up with this:

```
SELECT
   Dept.Id AS 'DeptId', User.Id AS 'UserId',
   DeptAccess.RightsLevel AS 'DeptRightsLevel',
   SiteAccess.RightsLevel AS 'SiteRightsLevel',
   CompanySiteAccess.RightsLevel AS 'CompanyRightsLevel'
FROM (Dept, User)
LEFT JOIN DeptAccess
   ON DeptAccess.DeptId=Dept.Id AND DeptAccess.UserId=User.Id
LEFT JOIN SiteAccess
   ON SiteAccess.SiteId=Dept.SiteId AND SiteAccess.UserId=User.Id
LEFT JOIN (
      SELECT
         Site.CompanyId,
         Site.Id AS 'SiteId',
         CompanyAccess.UserId,
         CompanyAccess.RightsLevel
      FROM Site
      INNER JOIN CompanyAccess
         ON Site.CompanyId=CompanyAccess.CompanyId
   ) AS CompanySiteAccess
   ON CompanySiteAccess.SiteId=Dept.SiteId AND CompanySiteAccess.UserId=User.Id
WHERE
   DeptAccess.RightsLevel IS NOT NULL OR
   SiteAccess.RightsLevel IS NOT NULL OR
   CompanySiteAccess.RightsLevel IS NOT NULL
```

Unfortunately, it contains a subquery, so MySQL will force `CompanySiteAccess` to be defined as its own view, but it should work correctly.